# How do i I use a virtualenv with pylint in flycheck?

Tags: python, flycheck

I use pylint in flycheck via the `python-flycheck` plugin. By default it uses emacs's virtualenv which lives here: `~/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default` on my machine. I would prefer if it used the virtualenv at the top-level of a git repo (in the `.venv` file).

I tend to just install everything in emacs's virtualenv with `~/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/pip3 install` but this probably isn't a good long-term solution.

Comment: have you tried setting `flycheck-python-pylint-executable`?

Comment: I have not... I guess I would need to make this a buffer local variable and set it whenever a buffer is opened?

Comment: i set my flycheck linter overrides globally. but that's me, on my systems, with my workflows. you do you.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that pylint needs source code to do its linting, so I'm trying to to leveral requirements.txt's in the each repository to get these requirements. I thought this stuff might be handled by `python-virtualenv`

Comment: there are multiple ways to answer your question. one is to set `flycheck-python-pylint-executable`, either explicitly or based on the path from your venv integration, in a directory local variable. check the `.dirs-local.el` in with your code. or, in your `init.el` set your checkers to just their exe name instead of their full path. then in your shell activate your venv, then start emacs. or, keep all of your tooling outside of your projects. or, try a different venv integration. there are several on melpa

Comment: Indeed. The answer I was hoping for was more along the lines of `python-pylint` uses the `virtualenv` implementation and you can use this library to make it using local virtualenv based on buffer, before I dive into too much coding. There seems to be some code in emacs for dealing with virtualenvs.